# How to know if a command given to execlp() exists?

Tags: c, unix, exec, fork, parent-child

I've searched quite a lot, but I still don't have an answer for this. I've got a program that creates other processes by asking the user the desired command, then I use execlp to open this new process. I wanted to know if there's an easy way to the parent process find out if the command was executed, or if the received command doesn't exist.

I have the following code:

```
if (executarComando(comando) != OK)
   fprintf(stderr,"Nao foi possivel executar esse comando. ");
```

where executarComando is:

```
int executarComando(char* cmd) {
if ( execlp("xterm", "xterm", "-hold", "-e", cmd, NULL) == ERROR) // error
    return ERROR;
return OK;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your `execlp` always succeeds; it's running `xterm`, not the command you're passing to the shell `xterm` runs. You will need to add some kind of communication channel between your program and this shell so that you can communicate back success or failure. I would do something like replacing the command with

```
( command ) 99>&- ; echo $? >&99
```

Then, open a pipe before forking to call `execlp`, and in the child, use `dup2` to create as file descriptor number 99 corresponding to the write end of the pipe. Now, you can read back the exit status of the command across the pipe.

Just hope `xterm` doesn't go closing all file descriptors on you; otherwise you're out of luck and you'll have to make a temporary fifo (via `mkfifo`) somewhere in the filesystem to achieve the same result.

Note that the number 99 was arbitrary; anything other than 0, 1, or 2 should work.

Comment: I haven't read about pipes yet, can you explain what your replacement does?

Answer (score 1):

There's no trivial way; a convention often used is that the `fork()`ed child will report the error and `exit(-1)` (or `exit(255)`) in the specific case where the `exec()` fails, and most commands avoid using that for their own failure modes.

Comment: The problem is that since I use xterm, execlp never fails, it just creates another shell using xterm, and then in that shell it says that the command doesn't exist.

Comment: It's still much the same thing, one level back; you can't *reliably* check it beforehand without introducing a race condition or possibly missing some potential failure mode (for example, you can't reliably verify that `execve()` won't get `ENOEXEC` or `ETXTBSY` without actually doing the `execve()`).